# svg size isn't working with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, size

svg size isn't working with javascript no mater what I do. I tried every thing but the size is all ways 0px * 0px. If I do it in the html code it works fine. Is there any know reason why it might not work. If you need some of my code just ask.

okay here's some code...

```
var svg = document.createElement("svg");
svg.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid black");
svg.setAttribute("height",20);
svg.setAttribute("width",20);
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(svg);
```

I also tried slightly different code. Also giving it a border gives it a small width and height(not the right one)

Comment: Yeah...we'll probably need to see the code. It would be best if you create the most minimal possible example that still reproduces your issue.

Comment: Please read the docs [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question so we could help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create SVG elements with createElement, createElement is for html elements only. You must use createElementNS with the SVG namespace i.e.

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
```

Answer (score -2):

**Maybe** because your `<svg>`is empty, try to add some content to your`<svg>`.

```
    var svg = document.createElement("svg");
    svg.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid black");
    svg.setAttribute("height",20);
    svg.setAttribute("width",20);
    svg.innerHTML = "Some content";
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(svg);
```

Comment: I tried that already. In html it worked, in javascript it didn't.

Comment: @technik3k Add content to your svg, from Javascript!

Comment: @technik3k the example above worked form in last Firefox.

Comment: Okay tried it and it worked but I need to have a <polygon> inside. I append it to the svg and it's there but nothing happens. Also why does giving it a width & height in javascript not work but in html it works